# Pandas - remove duplicate items completely from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to remove duplicate items completely from a pandas dataframe. For example, I have the dataframe:

```
  location     area
0  mountain view  1044ft2
1      palo alto     None
2  mountain view   890ft2
3     san carlos  1000ft2
4        belmont     None
```

What I want to do is find unique values in column `location` and remove any items that had duplicates altogether, completely, etc.. So the final product will look like this (notice `mountain view` is gone):

```
  location     area
1      palo alto     None
3     san carlos  1000ft2
4        belmont     None
```

Thanks.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('location',keep=False)`

Comment: Very simple! Thanks, didn't notice a duplicate question on SO, but appreciate your help @anky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset='location', keep=False)
```